# Single y-label and single x-label

Tags: plot, julia

I want to plot four different subplots with one ylabel and xlabel in Julia. However when I try to do this every subplot gets the ylabel and xlabel. Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you!

In the figure shown i would like to have one ylabel saying "Population levels". I also would like one xlabel below saying "Day Number". If it is possible i would like to have one title above saying "Population Parameters"

[image]

Comment: can you make a picture how you imagine your plot to look like? Perhaps you want just to have a single plot and then add lines to it where each line is e.g. in different corner of the plot?

Comment: Can you specify which plotting package you are using? Would you be happy with solutions in other plotting packages?